# realm uniqueValueForObject Swift3

Tags: ios, swift, realm

How to write swift3 syntax?
 Swift3 AnyObject Modified，no function

swift2:

```
  func uniqueValueForObject<U : Equatable>(objectKey: String, paramKey: String, type: U.Type)->[U]{
    var uniqueValues : [U] = [U]()
    for obj in self {

        if let o = obj.valueForKeyPath(forKeyPath: objectKey) {
            o.
            if let v = o.valueForKeyPath(paramKey){

                if(!uniqueValues.contains(v as! U)){
                    uniqueValues.append(v as! U)
                }

            }
        }

    }
    return uniqueValues
}
```

Can anyone help write swift3?

Comment: How is this related to Realm exactly?

Comment: extension Results

Answer (score 0):

If this is literally just a matter of updating the Realm Swift 2 syntax for Swift 3, then it should just look like this:

```
extension Results {
    func uniqueValueForObject<U: Equatable>(objectKey: String, paramKey: String, type: U.Type) -> [U] {
        var uniqueValues: [U] = [U]()
        for obj in self {
            if let o = obj.value(forKeyPath: objectKey) {
                if let v = (o as AnyObject).value(forKeyPath: paramKey) {

                    if !uniqueValues.contains(v as! U) {
                        uniqueValues.append(v as! U)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return uniqueValues
    }
}
```